# Embedding swank-clojure in java program

Tags: java, clojure, swank

Based on the Embedding section of http://github.com/technomancy/swank-clojure, 
I'm using the following to test it out.  Is there a better way to do 
this that doesn't use Compiler?  Is there a way to programmatically 
stop swank?  It seems start-repl takes control of the thread.  What 
would be a good way to spawn off another thread for it and be able to 
kill that thread programatically.

```
import clojure.lang.Compiler; 
import java.io.StringReader; 

public class Embed { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
        final String startSwankScript = 
            "(ns my-app\n" + 
                "  (:use [swank.swank :as swank]))\n" + 
                "(swank/start-repl) "; 
        Compiler.load(new StringReader(startSwankScript)); 
    } 
}
```

Any help much appreciated, 
hhh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would it be acceptable to you to implement the `Embed` class in Clojure? You could do that with `gen-class` (see [Meikel Brandmeyer's tutorial](http://kotka.de/blog/2010/02/gen-class_how_it_works_and_how_to_use_it.html) for details) and AOT compilation.

The code could go something like

```
(ns your-app.Embed
  (:require [swank.swank :as swank])
  (:gen-class
   :methods [[startSwank [] void]]))

(defn -startSwank []
  (swank/start-repl))
```

(add anything else you require); then in the Java part of your application, you could import your Clojure-prepared class, instantiate it and call `.startSwank()` on the instance.

Not sure about programmatically stopping Swank... I'd be curious to know of a good way to do that myself. (And I'll be back with an update if I figure it out; otherwise, I'd love to read somebody else's answer detailing how to go about that.)